# k8s:Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes

when intalled k8s node installation happened:

```
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the TLS Bootstrap...
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
error execution phase kubelet-start: error uploading crisocket: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you use `kubeadm` to install Kubernetes ? `kubeadm` will not manage `kubelet` and `kubectl` for you. Can you check if `kubelet` works properly ?

Comment: yes, i used kubeadm to intall, one of  my another kubelet machine could join the cluster, then  i found docker version on the two machines different, so i reinstall docker on the machine which didn't work, it successfully joined kubelet cluster.  thank you for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by Docker version mismatch on one of the machines. Problem was resolved after reinstalling Docker to correct version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i fixed it disabling swap with

```
swapoff -a
```